# Higher order residues using series

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

For example if we have any $f(z)$ with a singularity at $z=0$ but it is of order 12

Instead of using the limit definition, suppose $f(z)$ is in the form of:

$$f(z) = a_0z + a_1z^2 + a_2z^3 + ... + a_{-1}\frac{1}{z}$$

Is $a_{-1}$ still the residue of $f(z) $ at $z=0$? Even though this is of order 12?

What about then

$$\frac{f(z)}{(z+1)}$$

Will the residue at $z=0$ change?

Comment: Your hypothesis is contradictory, the pole in $f$ does not have order $12$.

Comment: I have not defined a SPECIFIC $f(z)$ what about $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^{12}}$?

Comment: You said $f$ is of a certain form, that limits what $f$ is.

Comment: Whatever be the order of the pole the residue always will be $a_{-1}$.